# Css - Create a pictograph with FontAwesome icons

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to represent the number of years as filled (blue) and unfilled (grey) circles using fontawesome icons. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without manually specifying the icons to fill in, but instead something like a [bar graph](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_progressbar.asp)?

The way I'm doing this now is:

```css
.container-icon{
  color: rgb(155,155,155);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css">
</head> 

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-header">
      <p>Item Number 1</p>
      <div class="container-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:blue"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:blue"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:blue"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
      </div>
      <p>Item Number 2</p>
      <div class="container-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:blue"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:blue"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
      </div>
      <p>Item Number 3</p>
      <div class="container-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:blue"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:blue"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:blue"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:blue"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there a more efficient way to create this pictograph, where I enter the number and that number of icons are filled in with blue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need an icon library for this, use CSS

```css
.container-icon {
  height: 20px;  /* adjust this to control the size */
  aspect-ratio: 5.5;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, blue calc(var(--n, 0)*20%), rgb(155, 155, 155) 0);
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(50% 50%, #000 87%, #0000 91%) 0/18.18% 100% space;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-header">
    <p>Item Number 1</p>
    <div class="container-icon" style="--n:1"></div>
    <p>Item Number 1</p>
    <div class="container-icon" style="--n:2"></div>
    <p>Item Number 2</p>
    <div class="container-icon" style="--n:3"></div>
    <p>Item Number 3</p>
    <div class="container-icon" style="--n:4"></div>
    <p>Item Number 3</p>
    <div class="container-icon" style="--n:5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another idea to better control the gap:

```css
.container-icon {
  --h: 30px; /* size */
  --g: 20px; /* gap */

  height: var(--h);
  width: calc(5*var(--h) + 4*var(--g));
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, blue calc(var(--n, 0)*20%), rgb(155, 155, 155) 0);
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(calc(var(--h)/2) at calc(var(--h)/2) 50%, #000 87%, #0000 91%) 0/calc(var(--h) + var(--g)) 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-header">
    <p>Item Number 1</p>
    <div class="container-icon" style="--n:1"></div>
    <p>Item Number 1</p>
    <div class="container-icon" style="--n:2"></div>
    <p>Item Number 2</p>
    <div class="container-icon" style="--n:3"></div>
    <p>Item Number 3</p>
    <div class="container-icon" style="--n:4"></div>
    <p>Item Number 3</p>
    <div class="container-icon" style="--n:5"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I wanted to have text centered in the last filled circle, would this method allow it? Is there the ability to increase the space between circles as well?

Comment: @Yolo_chicken updated with another version to control the gap but I don't understand for the text

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I am trying to have some text appear to the right of the last circle. I'm not sure how to make it work with your solution (which is great).

Comment: @Yolo_chicken make the div element display: inline-block and you can add text next to it